# How to convert a <table> element into SVG image?

Tags: export, html, svg-format

I want to get the SVG format about this `<table>` element in [this page](http://www.badd-cao.net:2345/browse/compound/C0283). It looks like this:

[image]

But I want to get it with a `SVG` image by *Mathematica*. Now I can get its HTML string:

```
url = "http://www.badd-cao.net:2345/browse/compound/C0283";
object = Cases[Import[url, "XMLObject"], 
   XMLElement["table", {_, "id" -> "target_relate_table"}, _], Infinity];
tablehtml = ExportString[First[object], "XML"]
```

> [image]

But How to export it into my dist as an `SVG` image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import it as a `Dataset`, then use `Export`.

```
dataset = Dataset[Import[url, {"HTML", "Data"}][[2]], MaxItems -> All];
Export["Table.svg", dataset];
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant method, and make a note here:`ImportString[tablehtml,{"HTML","Data"}]` or `Import[url,{"HTML","Data",2}]`

Comment: It would be nice to be able to select a particular table with the specified `id`